# Oracle sql to print value if it exists else print 'value' does not exist

Tags: oracle

I am looking for help towards - How to write a select statement (Oracle) to print a column from a table checking against specific value? For value that do not exist it should print a record saying 'value' does not exist.

E.g.

```
select username from dba_users where username in ('a','b','c').
```

Expected output -

```
username
========
a
b does not exist
c
```

Comment: Sorry, but you will probably get a better response if you phrase it like a question instead of a business requirement. This is a question/answer site after all, not a free consulting service.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a recent version of Oracle you could use `outer apply`, with a collection to hold the values you're looking for:

```
select coalesce (u.username, t.column_value || ' does not exist') as username
from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('SYS', 'XYZ', 'OUTLN')) t
outer apply (select username from all_users u where u.username = t.column_value) u;

USERNAME
------------------------------
SYS
XYZ does not exist
OUTLN
```

or just an outer join, which would work on earlier versions too:

```
select coalesce (u.username, t.column_value || ' does not exist') as username
from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('SYS', 'XYZ', 'OUTLN')) t
left join all_users u on u.username = t.column_value;

USERNAME
------------------------------
SYS
XYZ does not exist
OUTLN
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cfe860f1902829f64ff4c7e868940c09)